# Equal different types with different sizes

Tags: c, memory, types, variable-assignment

I want to assign something to a variable like this:

```
rtpArray[bn].ts06_timestamp = rtpArray[bn].timestamps_shm_ptr_aux[SCPAD_TS06];
```

The thing is, `rtpArray[bn].ts06_timestamp` this is of a type called `utdc_samples` that is bigger than `char`, and `rtpArray[bn].timestamps_shm_ptr_aux` is an array of `char`.

My question is, will this work?

Comment: Compile your code and the compiler will answer your question.

Comment: Compiling successfully doesn't mean it will *work*. There are plenty of things that will compile but make absolutely no sense in the problem domain.

Comment: My feeling is that this code is probably not correct - it is unlikely for a timestamp to be represented by a single byte. You probably need either a `memcpy` or a cast of the right-hand side to the appropriate type (and possibly an endianness-swap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rtpArray[bn].timestamps_shm_ptr_aux` is an array of chars, then `rtpArray[bn].timestamps_shm_ptr_aux[SCPAD_TS06]` is a single `char` value. There's no reason why you can't assign this to a larger integer type.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure about this, since you don't show the complete declarations that your code is using.

You are indexing on the right hand side, which implies that the result of the right hand size is a single character, i.e. a small integer. Assuming that `utdc_samples` is also an integer type, but larger than a `char`, then the assignment is fine.

Comment: @davmac It doens't matter, it will work anyway if a put sizeof(utdc_samples) right? I forgot about memcpy

Comment: @GonçaloSilvaSantos, putting `sizeof(utdc_samples)` instead of `sizeof rtpArray[bn].timestamps_shm_ptr_aux[SCPAD_TS06]` potentially causes undefined behaviour, since you may end up reading past the end of the array.

Comment: @davmac Perhaps. I find the question's code very hard to intepret safely since the types are not shown. I re-wrote, switching the assumptions around a bit.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an integer type on the LHS; just a numeric type.

Comment: @unwind, ok I have removed earlier comments.

Comment: @davmac didn't consider that. Although that is ery unlikely as the array is extremely big and utdc_samples is bigger than char but not that big. But yes it is not safe. Anyway, the reason i asked here is because i currently don't have acess to the compiler and needed to have it correct when i do.